# How to build uniqe key for HtmlHelper per View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I've created an HtmlHelperExtension. I'd like to put sth in Cache in order to improve performance. Data in cache should have scope per View (I mean every view should have own key in order to get data from cache). Is it possible to build such a key using only `HtmlHelper` (that is passed to an extension)?

```
public static HtmlResourceManagerHelper Resources(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
    var cacheData = this.cache.Get(BuildKeyForView(htmlHelper));
}

public static string BuildKeyForView(HtmlHelper htmlHelper) 
{
    // build key per view
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Razor or WebForm views, they both inherit from `BuildManagerCompiledView` that exposes the view path.
So you could use that as the cache key:

```
string key = String.Empty;
var view = htmlHelper.ViewContext.View as BuildManagerCompiledView;
if (view != null)
{
    key = view.ViewPath;    
}
//Check here key is not empty or use a default value if that makes sense on your use case
```

However if from a view, let's say the *Login* view, you render a partial view, let's say the *_LoginPartial* view, you need to be aware that the view path returned above will be the one of the main view *Login* in both cases.

Another option might be creating the cache key based on the controller, action and area names:

```
string controller = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
string action = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
string area = String.Empty;            
object areaObject;
if (htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens.TryGetValue("area", out areaObject))
{
    area = areaObject as string; 
}
string key = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", action, controller, area);
```

However in this case, if you return 2 different views from the same controller action depending on some condition, they would both get the same key. And if you return the same view from different controller actions, you would have different cache keys. So depending on your use case this might not be a valid approach.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah, I've though about it. Well, since there is not other reasonable approach, I'll choose the 1st way - my extension will be used only in view, not partial. Thanks!